# Doctrine - prevent new INSERT in related tables

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, orm, doctrine

Help/support application built with Zend Framework 1 and Doctrine 1.2.4.

Problem: when creating new support ticket without assigning `staff_id` (support personnel) at first, Doctrine inserts empty row in `staff` table, because `staff_id` is NULL, and no matching `id` with `NULL` value could be found in `staff` table.

New ticket is created, note NULL value for `staff_id`

```
INSERT INTO tickets (closable, emergency, survey_sent, brands_id, departments_id, categories_id, status_id, staff_id, subject, contacts_id, mask, initial_categories_id, last_opened, last_activity, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('0', '1', '0', '1', '4', '6', '1', NULL, 'Cancellation Request', '5463', 'MQXB-39568', '6', '2012-06-14 03:15:49', '2012-06-14 03:15:49', '2012-06-14 03:15:49', '2012-06-14 03:15:49')
```

New row in `staff` table with some default values, this is **the problem**.

```
INSERT INTO staff (enable_dst, last_page, external_links, replies_per_page, active) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', '10', '1')
```

wild query appears

```
DELETE FROM staff_index WHERE (id = '197')
```

and now `ticket_posts` (post = staff note) table is updated with newly inserted ticket ID, and newly inserted blank row in `staff` table (`staff_id` should be NULL here)

```
UPDATE ticket_posts SET tickets_id = '12455', staff_id = '197', updated_at = '2012-06-14 03:15:49' WHERE id = '48113'
```

I've "solved" empty rows by setting second column (username) to not null, but not a real solution.

---

Is there a way to tell Doctrine, nothing to do here, move on?

---

( ^ bottom line )

Comment: Show us the code of your insert

Comment: @j0k basically `$new_ticket = new Tickets(); $new_ticket->fromArray($formData);`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/working-with-models.html#clearing-related-records

```
public function preSave()
{
    if (empty($this->staff_id))
        $this->clearRelated('Staff');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you accessed the Staff property on the Ticket instance before persisting the object? This could be the problem that Doctrine is creating an "empty" record.

```
$ticket = new Ticket();
$ticket->Staff = NULL; # Doctrine will now add empty record.
$ticket->save();
```

Comment: Hi, no, it is populated from POST array... `$new_ticket = new Tickets(); $new_ticket->fromArray($formData);`, if no one is assigned, staff_id is empty '' ... thanks.

Comment: Does your form has "Staff" relation somewhere? That could be the problem if for eg. none is picked from <select> or you have a hidden "staff_id" in the form.